# How to calculate double series of this form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have stumbled upon a weird series expression. It looks like

\begin{equation}
S=\sum_{i=0}^\infty{A^i}{x^{\sum_{j=0}^ij}}
\end{equation}

Alternatively, it is

\begin{equation}
1+Ax+A^2x^3+A^3x^6+A^4x^{10}+\dots
\end{equation}

I have no reason to believe this summation has a good closed form expression. If you prove there is no good closed form expression, I would appreciate it as well.

Thanks!

Comment: The sum in the exponent can be expressed as $\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$. If you put $u=x^{1/2}$, this lets you write the summation as $$S=\sum_{i=0}^\infty A^i u^{i(i+1)}.$$

Comment: @Clayton I can edit the question if you suggest, but I still cannot solve it, even with your tip.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a tip; it is just an observation that may make the problem more approachable.